# std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::vector<>>> の値を初期化するにはどう記述すればよい？

Tags: c++

以下の場合、dataに初期値(2*2配列、値1)を与えるにはどの様に書けば良いでしょうか？

```
struct 構造体名 {
    int x;
    int y;
}    

std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::vector<構造体名>>> data;
```

以下の様に試してみましたが、配列サイズが０な為か値が出力されませんでした。

```
for (const auto& data : *data) {
    for (const auto& data_info: data) {
    data_info.x = 1;
    data_info.y = 1;
    }
}
```

※追記

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

struct SomeData {
    int  x;
    int  y;
    SomeData():
        x(0),
        y(0){}
    SomeData(int _num1, int _num2):
        x(_num1),
        y(_num2){}
};

struct Data{
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::vector<SomeData>>> data;  //☆
};

void func(const Data& data_info)
{
    auto data = std::make_shared<std::vector<std::vector<SomeData>>>();
    data->push_back({{1,1},{1,1}});
　　　　　　　　data->push_back({{1,1},{1,1}});
    
　　　　　　　　for (const auto& data : *data) {
        for (const auto& data_info : data){
            std::cout << "x :"<< data_info.x << std::endl;
            std::cout << "y :" << data_info.y << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(const Data& data_info)
{
    func(data_info);

    return 0;
}
```

**出力結果:**

```
x :1
y :1
x :1
y :1
x :1
y :1
x :1
y :1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> この場合、dataに初期値(2*2配列、値1)を与えるにはどの様に書けば良いでしょうか？

参考　initializer_list を使わない場合の例です。

```
using T = std::vector<SomeData>;
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>> data = std::make_shared<std::vector<T>>(2, T(2, SomeData(1, 1)));
```

初期化ではなく後で初期値を設定したい場合の例です。

```
using T = std::vector<SomeData>;
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>> data;

std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>> tmp = std::make_shared<std::vector<T>>(2, T(2, SomeData(1, 1)));
data.swap(tmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

初期化で全てを済ませたい場合は、以下のような感じです。

```cpp
using T = std::vector<構造体名>;
auto data = std::make_shared<std::vector<T>>(
    std::initializer_list<T>{
        {{1, 1}, {1, 1}},
        {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}});
```

`push_back()` を使ってもいい場合は、

```cpp
auto data = std::make_shared<std::vector<std::vector<構造体名>>>();
data->push_back({{1, 1}, {1, 1}});
data->push_back({{1, 1}, {1, 1}});
```

Comment: '''std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::vector<構造体名>>> data;'''
の部分が定義済みで変更できない場合、dataにpush_back()の方法を用いることはできますか？

Comment: 「定義済みで変更できない」とはどういう状況でしょうか。状況がわかるように具体的なコードで質問文を更新してください。push_back() を試してみたのですか?

Comment: 追記したところで色々といじっていたら動きました。どうやら「auto data → data_info.data」とすれば☆の箇所を消さずに済むようです。